# python: csv.reader & unicode (and postgres)

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a CSV with a unicode character (the spanish ñ character). Trying to import this into a utf8-encoded postgres table. The following code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'), delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    values = [None if x == '' else x for x in row]
    query = 'INSERT INTO %s.rosters VALUES(%s)' % (self.schema, ','.join(['%s'] * len(values)))
    self.executequery(query, values)
```

Yields `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf1616461`. So, changing it to:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'), delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    values = [None if x == '' else unicode(x, 'utf-8') for x in row]
    query = 'INSERT INTO %s.rosters VALUES(%s)' % (self.schema, ','.join(['%s'] * len(values)))
    self.executequery(query, values)
```

Yields `'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 21-24: invalid data`

Is there any way to resolve this?

*update* The file was not UTF-8; it was Windows-1252. Changing the assignment of the values list to:

```
values = [None if x == '' else unicode(x, 'cp1252') for x in row]
```

Fixes the issue!

Comment: What is the encoding of your original file? You will need to know this in order to create the `unicode` object. You are trying to decode using UTF-8, but that's obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the CSV file is encoded in UTF-8? If it is, you'd see something like this:

```
$ file foo.txt 
foo.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

If it doesn't say UTF-8, then you probably have to decode it with a different codec, such as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: ARGH. It's actually windows-1252, even though the file command says ASCII. Is there some way to properly open that file w/ piping it through iconv or something?